# Grid.Width="*" is not in a correct format

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Name="Panel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="100" Width="*" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want the inner grid to fill the whole width of the screen. so I thought putting a `*` will do that. but it says it is not in a correct format.

How can I set the inner grid to fill the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Width` property is of type `double` and doesn't accept a value of type `GridLength`. Therefore you will get an exception saying **"'*' string cannot be converted to Length."**

Also you should not set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`. If you wish to stretch the Width of control set it as `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`.

If you set `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` then elements are aligned to the left of the parent element's allocated layout space.

You can get more useful info at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx). I would suggest to go over it so you can get more idea, how to place/arrange control in a better way on UI.

```
<Grid Name="Panel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Comment: thanks, But I want it to be at the top as a banner. with a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

just set the **HorizontalAlignment** property of the grid to stretch like this..and remove the width property..

```
<Grid Name="Panel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="100"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    </Grid>
```

hope it will solve your problem..